# Check which of the buttons was "click" eventListener

Tags: javascript, html

```
    var one= document.getElementById("OneOp");
    one.addEventListener("click",function1,false);

    var two= document.getElementById("twoOp");
    two.addEventListener("click", function1,false);

    var three= document.getElementById("threeOp");
    three.addEventListener("click", function1,false);
```

all of them go to fucntion1, once the I need to know which button, and then use than in information in function1, (out of one two or three). if there any way to do check it? I was thinking implementing a if else statement of some kind, but I can't seem to figure out the right sintax using javascript.

I am very new at javascript, I would appreciate any input.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `target` property of the [**event**](https://developer.mozilla.org/ar/docs/Web/API/Event/target) object

```
function function1(event){
    var clickedId = event.target.id;
    if(clickedId == 'OneOp'){
    }
    else if
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: is event a keyword of the JavaScript library?

Comment: @JJ12, it is not a keyword. However, it is a javascript object that is automatically passed in as the first parameter to *event* handlers such as *click*

Comment: alright, sorry I am still learning the basics. I believe I now understand how it works. thanks @AmmmarCSE

Comment: @JJ12, dont be sorry. We all need to start from somewhere :) Let me know if you need more help/have anymore questions

Comment: Use `this.id` instead of `event.target.id` to ensure you get the bound element.